# Yummly API " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : "

Tags: javascript, json, api, jsonp

I am trying to request data from the Yummly API with the following call

```
       $http.jsonp('http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=' 
          +  $scope.apiId 
          + '&_app_key=' 
          + $scope.apiKey 
          + '&allowedAllergy[]=396^Dairy-Free' 
          + '/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK' ).success(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
          }).error(function(error) {

        });
```

And I keep getting this error saying " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : " and when I click it takes me to the response.  It is also not logging the data in the console.

Comment: And what library or functions are you using for the `$http.jsonp` function ?

Comment: sorry realized I forgot to add that info.. im using angular.js

Comment: "Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sever is returning JSON - *not* [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). This in turns causes the exception when the *JSON* text is executed in the hosting `<script>` context.

Running the following code in the console will generate the same error because `{..}` is in a Statement context:

```
{"foo": "bar"}
```

On the other hand, a valid *JSONP* response should look like this (which is valid syntax because `{..}` is in an Expression context):

```
JSON_CALLBACK({"foo": "bar"})
```

Comment: So then how would I return JSONP? The docs for Yummly says it supports JSONP.

Comment: @user1876246 The URI appears to be wrong. It should likely end in `&callback=...` as opposed to `/?callback=..`. In any case, look at the network monitor (for actual resource request and actual response).

Comment: Yes @user1876246!! Thanks! I have no idea where that syntax came from but it was that. Thanks so much!